# NLog exceptions as Trace in Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Hi I want to log exceptions to Application Insights using NLog. I integrated both my project and application insights. The real problem here is NLog has different logger types such as warn, info, error, debug, fatal. When I am trying to log using these in app insights I get all these exceptions as Trace errors. Please find in the below screen shot. I want them to be there name as per the severity.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Trace Telemetry has a property called 'Severity', see also [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics#tracktrace) so the severity is logged correctly.

According to your screenshot everything is right, i see Error Info, Info and Debug so what is wrong?

The yellow part is just the type of telemetry (Trace) and has nothing to do with the severity.