# Configure Layout of Application Logs in Azure Log Stream

Tags: .net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-webapi, nlog

I have an Net Core Web API hosted in an Azure App Service and I am trying to format the output of the Azure Log Stream in the same way the Console is formatted in my Development environment.

I am using NLog for this and I am redirecting all logs to the Console using the NLog ColoredConsole:

```
"target": {
      "type": "ColoredConsole",
      "layout": "${var_layout}",
      "rowHighlightingRules": [
        {
          "condition": "level == LogLevel.Trace",
          "foregroundColor": "DarkGray"
        },
        {
          "condition": "level == LogLevel.Debug",
          "foregroundColor": "DarkGray"
        },
        {
          "condition": "level == LogLevel.Warning",
          "foregroundColor": "Yellow"
        },
        {
          "condition": "level == LogLevel.Error",
          "foregroundColor": "Red"
        },
        {
          "condition": "level == LogLevel.Fatal",
          "foregroundColor": "Yellow",
          "backgroundColor": "Red"
        }
      ]
    }
```

In my Startup.cs I removed `AddConsole()` option and I configured NLog to send all formatted output to the ColoredConsole.

This works well on my local Console and everything is formatted as expected.

However in the Azure Log Stream I can still see the default formatting (all white on black background) and layout (my custom logged data with NLog is missing).

My question is: why the Azure Log Stream is not showing the formatted output? Is that not showing exactly what the Console is logging?

If not, how can I format the Azure Log Stream output?

Comment: When reading about Azure Log Streaming, then one either uses `AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics` (Writes to FileSystem and Blob) or one writes to a log-file in the `/home/LogFiles`-directory. But neither solution provides coloring or highlighting. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-cloud-logging-with-Azure-function-or-AWS-lambda#writing-to-azure-diagnostics-log-stream

Comment: Maybe ApplicationInsights will provide the coloring you need based on LogLevel. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/58830106/193178

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid your need is **not supported** on Azure.

The Log Stream just output the console message, but not a real console, so it would be a bit tricky with colors.

Just like the [link](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-cloud-logging-with-Azure-function-or-AWS-lambda#writing-to-azure-diagnostics-log-stream) *Rolf Kristensen* post, there is no solution about colored console with any Azure Log system.